# Extract string from HTML tag [VB.Net]

Tags: html, regex, vb.net

My html (TextBox1.Text):

```
<b>
Hello world!
</b>
```

My VB.Net regex code:

```
Dim findtext2 As String = "(?<=<b>)(.*?)(?=</b>)"
Dim myregex2 As String = TextBox1.Text
Dim doregex2 As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(myregex2, findtext2)
Dim matches2 As String = ""
For Each match2 As Match In doregex2
    matches2 = matches2 + match2.ToString + Environment.NewLine
Next
MsgBox(matches2)
```

And it doesn't work! Yet after hours of researching i found out that this regex is working on single line only, which means it would work on **`<b>Hello world!</b>`**, but won't work if there are line breaks between html tags.

Comment: `Regex.Matches(myregex2, findtext2, RegexOptions.Singleline)`

Comment: Try again, I get a match.

Comment: There's no need to put `[VB.Net]` in the title since you've already specified the language in the "Tags" section.